# Keypressed event in UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have 10 textfields, in which I could enter only one character in each textfield. After a character is entered in each textfield, the focus should move to the next one. Similarly when i delete character from a textfield by pressing the backspace or delete, i need to get the focus to the previous textfield. If I could get the keypressed event, I could do that. Right now I am not able to find any keypressed event examples.

Comment: i hope u should write logic when first textFeild Resign Responder then 2nd text feild will Become Responder .put tags For Testfeilds and get textfeilds From view With Tag.write For Loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

Implement the delegate methods in the protocol. You can achieve the things you wanted.

You can set the focus by using the method `becomeFirstResponder` to the required textfield.

Have a look at the delegate method

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

So that could solve your problem.

Comment: How could i detect that a particular key pressed is backspace or delete?

Comment: See, anyhow you would support only one character. Once a character is entered, you would get the length of the string and would move to the next field. If he deletes the character, then the length would become zero. Then, you move to the previous one. That kind of logic you implement. This is just an idea.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that you're always going to be one character behind, since if you query the `.Text` property it's going to have the old value, and I'm not sure how you're supposed to get the value that it *will* have after returning `true`.

Comment: any solution for Kirk Woll observation

Answer (score 4):

Based on Aadhira's answer, but taking into account Kirk Woll's comment, you can generate what the latest text will be by using `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  NSString *value = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  NSLog(@"value: %@", value);
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you directions:

1. Assign tag to each text field.
2. [Implement UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextField). There are all the methods you need to detect any event that takes place inside the text field. In each method you can check the tag and move focus properly.

Hint: you can use `[mainView viewWithTag:XX]` to quickly pick the text field you need.

Each time the text is changed you can check the text property of the text field and it will give you the answer which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol into your code and this method will tell you when you start begin editing in text field

**– textFieldShouldBeginEditing:**

and you can set the if condition in this method according to your requirement...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `textfieldDelegate` methods.

In your `textFieldShouldReturn` method you have to set your responders like

```
if (textfield == textField1)
{
    [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if (textField == textField2)
{
    [textField3 becomeFirstResponder];
}
else
{
    [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
}

return YES; // as method return type is BOOL.
```